# Ruby HTTParty soundcloud gem error

Tags: ruby, soundcloud, httparty

I was experimenting with the soundcloud gem and suddenly I always get an error with every request I make.

For example this following code:

```
require 'soundcloud'

client = SoundCloud.new(:client_id => MY_CLIENT_ID)

track_url = 'https://soundcloud.com/sohight/sohight-cheevy-money-is-love-out-now'

track = client.get('/resolve', :url => track_url)
puts track.genre
```

Anyone knows why I get this error?

```
/Users/angel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/httparty-0.13.4/lib/httparty/hash_conversions.rb:33:in `normalize_param': uninitialized constant HTTParty::HashConversions::ERB (NameError)
from /Users/angel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/httparty-0.13.4/lib/httparty/hash_conversions.rb:15:in `block in to_params'
from /Users/angel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/httparty-0.13.4/lib/httparty/hash_conversions.rb:15:in `each'
from /Users/angel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/httparty-0.13.4/lib/httparty/hash_conversions.rb:15:in `map'
from /Users/angel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/httparty-0.13.4/lib/httparty/hash_conversions.rb:15:in `to_params'
from /Users/angel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/httparty-0.13.4/lib/httparty/request.rb:148:in `normalize_query'
from /Users/angel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/httparty-0.13.4/lib/httparty/request.rb:180:in `query_string'
from /Users/angel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/httparty-0.13.4/lib/httparty/request.rb:70:in `uri'
from /Users/angel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/httparty-0.13.4/lib/httparty/request.rb:157:in `setup_raw_request'
from /Users/angel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/httparty-0.13.4/lib/httparty/request.rb:98:in `perform'
from /Users/angel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/httparty-0.13.4/lib/httparty.rb:521:in `perform_request'
from /Users/angel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/httparty-0.13.4/lib/httparty.rb:459:in `get'
from /Users/angel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/soundcloud-0.3.2/lib/soundcloud/client.rb:27:in `block in get'
from /Users/angel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/soundcloud-0.3.2/lib/soundcloud/client.rb:145:in `call'
from /Users/angel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/soundcloud-0.3.2/lib/soundcloud/client.rb:145:in `handle_response'
from /Users/angel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/soundcloud-0.3.2/lib/soundcloud/client.rb:26:in `get'
from sound.rb:9:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly a bug in HTTParty.

Line 33 of `hash_conversions.rb`:

```
param << "#{key}=#{ERB::Util.url_encode(value.to_s)}&"
```

Put this at the top of your script and try again:

```
require 'erb'
```